# Iterating thourgh a SRT file until index is found

Tags: python-3.x

This might sound like "Iterate through file until condition is met" question (which I have already checked), but it doesn't work for me.

Given a SRT file (any) as `srtDir`, I want to go to the index `choice` and get timecode values and caption values.

I did the following, which is supposed to iterate though the SRT file until condition is met:

```
import os

srtDir = "./media/srt/001.srt"
index = 100 #Index. Number is an examaple
found = False

with open(srtDir, "r") as SRT:
    print(srtDir)
    content = SRT.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    for x in content:
        print(x)
        if x == index:
            print("Found")
            found = True
            break

if not found:
    print("Nothing was found")
```

As said, it is supposed to iterate until Index is found, but it returns "Nothing is found", which is weird, because I can see the number printed on screen.

What did I do wrong?

(I have checked libraries, AFAIK, there's no one that can return timecode and captions given the index)

Comment: You should post the srt file if you want us to debug it.

Comment: Also does https://github.com/cdown/srt not work for you?

Comment: @Wassinger i've been looking at it but i don't see how (i'm kinda new to python in general). I can't post the SRT file since it's supposed to work with any SRT i give to the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type mismatch in your code: `index` is an `int` but `x` in your loop is a `str`. In Python, `100 == "100"` evaluates to `False`. The solution to this kind of bug is to adopt a well-defined data model and write library methods that apply it consistently.

However, with something like this, it's best not to reinvent the wheel and let other people do the boring work for you.

```
import srt

# Sample SRT file
raw = '''\
1
00:31:37,894 --> 00:31:39,928
OK, look, I think I have a plan here.

2
00:31:39,931 --> 00:31:41,931
Using mainly spoons,

3
00:31:41,933 --> 00:31:43,435
we dig a tunnel under the city and release it into the wild.
'''

# Parse and get index
subs = list(srt.parse(raw))

def get_index(n, subs_list):
    for i in subs_list:
        if i.index == n:
            return i
    return None

s = get_index(2, subs)

print(s)
```

See:

- https://github.com/cdown/srt
- https://srt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html
- https://srt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html